# Create own action to clone/duplicate TYPO3 8.7 extbase object with nested child elements

Tags: object, controller, typo3, extbase, typo3-8.x

I build my extbased TYPO3 extension in TYPO3 8.7 . It is a Backend-Module. In the controller, i write my own action to clone the object. 
In this example, i want to clone/duplicate the object 'Campaign' and safe it with a modified title, like add the 'copy' text to the title. 
But the new object should have also its own new child elements that must be exact copies. 
When the action is called, i get only a copy of the Object, but no childs. Is there an example or best case how to handle this task? I did not find, even i found some questions and answers that are on the same topic, but older version. i hope that upd to date, there is a more straight forward solution. Thank you for every hint that points me to the right ideas and maybe an up to date and version example.  Here is what i have i my controller. How do i implement recursiv copying of all child elements (and some childs have childs, too)?

```
    /**
     * action clone
     * @param \ABC\Copytest\Domain\Model\Campaign $campaign
     * @return void
     * @var \ABC\Copytest\Domain\Model\Campaign $newCampaign
     */

    public function cloneAction(\ABC\Copytest\Domain\Model\Campaign $campaign) {
        $newCampaign = $this->objectManager->get("ABC\Copytest\Domain\Model\Campaign");
        $properties = $campaign->_getProperties();
        unset($properties['uid']);
        foreach ($properties as $key => $value) {
            $newCampaign->_setProperty($key, $value);
        }
        $newCampaign->_setProperty('title', $properties['title']. ' COPY');
        $this->campaignRepository->add($newCampaign);
        $this->addFlashMessage('Clone was created', '', \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\AbstractMessage::OK);
        $this->redirect('list');
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am aware that this question has been answered a long time ago. But I want to provide my solution to create a deep copy for further reference. Tested on TYPO3 9.5.8.

```
private function deepcopy($object)
{
    $clone = $this->objectManager->get(get_class($object));
    $properties = \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Reflection\ObjectAccess::getGettableProperties($object);
    foreach ($properties as $propertyName => $propertyValue) {
        if ($propertyValue instanceof \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage) {
            $v = $this->objectManager->get(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage::class);
            foreach($propertyValue as $subObject) {
                $subClone = $this->deepcopy($subObject);
                $v->attach($subClone);
            }
        } else { 
            $v = $propertyValue;
        }
        if ($v !== null) {
            \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Reflection\ObjectAccess::setProperty($clone, $propertyName, $v);
        }
    }
    return $clone;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! One small thing to add if f.e. image is empty:if(null !== $v) {
    \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Reflection\ObjectAccess::setProperty($clone, $propertyName, $v);
   }

Comment: Thanks martin, I added that part.

Comment: I finally came back to the project and could now implement this solution. Thank you Markus.

Answer (score 0):

There is one approach which tackles this usecase from a different POV, namely that request argument values without an identity are automatically put into fresh objects which can then be persisted. This basically clones the original objects. This is what you need to do:

1. Add a view which has fields for all properties of your object, hidden fields are fine too. This can for example be an `edit` view with a separate submit button to call your `clone` action.
2. Add a `initializeCloneAction()` and get the raw request arguments via `$this->request->getArguments()`.
3. Now do `unset($arguments[<argumentName>]['__identity']);`, do the same for every relation your object has if you want copies instead of shared references.
4. Store the raw request arguments again via `$this->request->setArguments($arguments)`.
5. Finally allow the creation of new objects in the property mapping configuration of your argument and possibly all relation properties.

This is how a full `initializeCloneAction()` could look like:

```php
public function initializeCloneAction()
{
    $arguments = $this->request->getArguments();

    unset(
        $arguments['campaign']['__identity'],
        $arguments['campaign']['singleRelation']['__identity'],
    );

    foreach (array_keys($arguments['campaign']['multiRelation']) as $i) {
        unset($arguments['campaign']['multiRelation'][$i]['__identity']);
    }

    $this->request->setArguments($arguments);

    // Allow object creation now that we have new objects
    $this->arguments->getArgument('campaign')->getPropertyMappingConfiguration()
        ->setTypeConverterOption(PersistentObjectConverter::class, PersistentObjectConverter::CONFIGURATION_CREATION_ALLOWED, true)
        ->allowCreationForSubProperty('singleRelation')
        ->getConfigurationFor('multiRelation')
            ->allowCreationForSubProperty('*');
}
```

Now if you submit your form using the `clone` action, your `clone` action will get a fully populated but new object which you can store in your repository as usual. Your `cloneAction()` will then be very simple:

```php
public function cloneAction(Campaign $campaign)
{
    $this->campaignRepository->add($campaign);

    $this->addFlashMessage('Campaign was copied successfully!');
    $this->redirect('list');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this whole example and idea. I am still trying to get it working. I built a simple extension with on model that has only one 1:n relation to have an easy test szenarion. I struggle with this part in the initializeCloneAction right now: 
`foreach (array_keys($arguments['campaign']['multiRelation']) as $i) {
        unset($arguments['campaign']['multiRelation'][$i]['__identity']);
    }`
I get the Error:
PHP Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Comment: I changed the code to fit to my model like this:
`foreach (array_keys($arguments['campaign']['phase']) as $i) {
        unset($arguments['campaign']['phase'][$i]['__identity']);
    }` But it dont work yet. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Did you make sure to have a field for every object, you need all properties of all related objects too, at least as hidden fields.

Comment: I get the Error: PHP Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given. This is when I call the cloneAction. All the models (Campaign-Model with two 1:n Childs called Phase) have only one property 'title' right now, to keep testing simple. These titles are correctly shown in the form-fields of the page where i then call the cloneAction. Is there any extension in the TER you know about, that uses kind of cloneAction, so I could have a look at the whole code. I didnt find one yet.

Comment: No, there is no public extension AFAIK. Notice that you should leave off the relation parts if you don't have any relations ATM. Otherwise you need to ensure you have fields for these as mentioned.

Comment: I think my error is in the form, as you already guessed. How do I correctly represent the 1:n relation in the form?  I have the form in a view called Preclone `<f:form action="clone" name="campaign" object="{campaign}" >
            <f:render partial="Campaign/FormFields" arguments="{campaign:campaign}" />
            <f:form.submit value="CLONE now" />
        </f:form>` and inside the Campaign/FormFields.html `<f:for each="{campaign.phase}" as="phase">Phase:<f:form.textfield property="phase.title" value="{phase.title}" /><br /></f:for>` to iterate on the child elements.

Comment: Yeah, the last one needs to use `iteration` of `f:for` and then `property="phase.{i}" value="{phase}"`

Comment: That was was it, it solved the whole problem. Thank you for making me a litte less stupid.

Comment: Thanks for showing me things I still need to add to my answer. ;-)

Comment: Sorry, after i set my question to "answered", I recognized that I forgot to uncomment the part for the creation of the subProperties, so that the childs were moved instead of cloned. When I uncomment the lines in the Controller, I get the Error: `Exception while property mapping at property path "phase.Array": Creation of objects not allowed. To enable this, you need to set the PropertyMappingConfiguration Value "CONFIGURATION_CREATION_ALLOWED" to TRUE` 
Your Controller-code after  `// Allow object creation now that we have new objects` didnt work for me yet. Im still working on it.

Comment: I tried to change the PropertyMappingConfiguration to allow creation of Child-Elements, but I get this Error now: `Call to a member function forProperty() on null ` Maybe I should try to show off the complete code from controller, template and output, so one can see my mistake(s)?

Comment: You can leave a gist link in the comments here.

Comment: I am still trying, and I redone my testextension. But now `->setTypeConverterOption(PersistentObjectConverter::class, PersistentObjectConverter::CONFIGURATION_CREATION_ALLOWED, true)` leads to the error `Class 'ABC\Copytest\Controller\PersistentObjectConverter' not found` Why? How to solve this?

Comment: I had to set `use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Property\TypeConverter\PersistentObjectConverter;` , that solved this problem.

Comment: Can you edit my comment or make a gist with suggested edits to clarify this for other people? I must admit that I've lost track of the differences between my suggested and your current state.

Comment: That is the actual code of my test extension with a base object that has 1:n childs [gist](https://gist.github.com/DeepDeeh/1ccd2dcbd684830ef8486cfb674e49ca)

Comment: I just updated the gist due to one typeing error I found.

Answer (score 0):

If you have "LazyLoadingProxy" instance in your object you need add one more conditions.

```
if ($propertyValue instanceof \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\LazyLoadingProxy) {
   $objectStorage = $propertyValue->_loadRealInstance();
}
```

This is my solution for "deepcopy" function:

```
    private function deepcopy($object)
    {
        $clone = $this->objectManager->get(get_class($object));
        $properties = \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Reflection\ObjectAccess::getGettableProperties($object);
        foreach ($properties as $propertyName => $propertyValue) {
            if ($propertyValue instanceof \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage) {
                $objectStorage = $this->objectManager->get(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage::class);
                foreach ($propertyValue as $subObject) {
                    $subClone = $this->deepcopy($subObject);
                    $objectStorage->attach($subClone);
                }
            } elseif ($propertyValue instanceof \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\LazyLoadingProxy) {
                $objectStorage = $propertyValue->_loadRealInstance();
            } else {
                $objectStorage = $propertyValue;
            }
            if ($objectStorage !== null) {
                \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Reflection\ObjectAccess::setProperty($clone, $propertyName, $objectStorage);
            }
        }

        return $clone;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a good solution is, to emulate the backend-function.
See the code-example (german text)
http://blog.marcdesign.ch/2015/05/27/typo3-extbase-objekte-kopieren/

The general idea is to extend the `TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler` and use the parent-method `copyRecord`. You declare your predefined backend-user to `$this->BE_USER` in your extend class. The obejct of your predefined backenduser can you get by using the class `TYPO3\\CMS\\Backend\\FrontendBackendUserAuthentication` and the known name of you predefined backenduser. Your user should have admin-rights and you should define the `$BE_USER->uc_default['copyLevels']= '9999';` and declare `$BE_USER->uc = $BE_USER->uc_default`.
I have not checked, if the declaration `$GLOBALS['PAGES_TYPES'][254]['allowedTables'] = '*';` is really needed.
The method `copyRecord`itself needs mainly the table-name, the `uid`-value, the `pid`-value and a language-object as parameters.The languages-object can you get `$GLOBALS['lang']`, which can although be generated by instanciating `\TYPO3\CMS\Lang\LanguageService` to `$GLOBALS['lang']` and `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Charset\CharsetConverter` to `$GLOBALS['LANG']->csConvObj`.

Sorry about my poor english.

Comment: Please find an English version to link to. Also, linked content is not considered part of a StackOverflow answer. Without the link your post is an answer, but maybe not a very detailed one and definitly one without any explanation. Maybe revisit [answer]. Have fun.

Comment: I can't copy foreign content (copyright of the owner).  Better than nothing is a link. The main text is the code-example. Use google to translate the text, which has not much informations. If you dislike this answer, give it a thumb down.

Comment: You cannot copy. You should however summarise what you have linked (not "what" it achieves or describes, but "how" it does so). And no, a link is not better than nothing. Link-only answers routinely get deleted. Please understand that your answer in its current form is evaluated as "emulate the backend-function", and that seems rather brief to me.